# TOC of separated articles

Tags: table-of-contents, journal

I have a ten separated articles journal.  Can I construct one TOC for the journal that contains all that articles?

The example indicated that the TOC generated from single file. In my case, I have 10 separated files. Of course one can have TOC in each file. I need (if possible) to make a single TOC that contains all other TOC from the 10 files.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: yes, thank you. this is duplicate question. sorry.